# What is the "Adobe implementation" of ASCII85 encoding that Python emulates?

Tags: python, base64, adobe, ascii85, base85

In the documentation for the [base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) module, the `base64.a85encode` function takes an `adobe` parameter, which is described as follows:

> adobe controls whether the encoded byte sequence is framed with <~ and
> ~>, which is used by the Adobe implementation.

What is this Adobe implementation? The [PostScript](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/actionscript/articles/PLRM.pdf) and [PDF](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) references require only that ASCII85-encoded data is terminated by `~>`, not that it is also prefixed with `<~`.